# Example of computing Lie bracket on $T_eG$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I understand the following construction: For a Lie group $G$, let $\widetilde{\text{Lie}}(G)$ denote the set of right-invariant vector fields on $G$ - this is a finite dimensional Lie algebra under the Lie bracket of vector fields. There is an isomorphism $\varphi\colon\widetilde{\text{Lie}}(G)\to T_eG$ defined by $X\mapsto X_e$, hence we can define a Lie bracket on $T_eG$ by $[A,B]:=[\tilde{A},\tilde{B}]_e$ for $A,B\in T_eG$ where $\tilde{A},\tilde{B}\in\widetilde{\text{Lie}}(G)$ are such that $\varphi(\tilde{A})=A$ and $\varphi(\tilde{B})=B$.

To understand this a bit more, I would like to *compute* the Lie bracket on $T_eG$ for an explicit Lie group $G$. In particular, I have the following question:

> **Question**. What is the Lie bracket on $T_eG$ for the Lie group $G=\text{Gl}(n;\mathbb{R})$?

I know $T_eG=M(n;\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

For matrix groups the Lie bracket on the associated Lie algebra is generally the commutator of matrices. The justification is as follows.

In an open neighbourhood around the identity $e$ we can consider a path $\gamma(t)$ with $\gamma(0)=e$. Since we're in $GL_n$ this path has an inverse $\gamma^{-1}(t)$ which is also identity $t=0$.

Now the associated Lie algebra element is the derivative at $t=0$

$$\gamma'(0)=A\in T_eG $$

Furthermore the inverse has a derivative at the identity which we can find by taking the derivative of $\gamma(t)\gamma^{-1}(t)=e$ at $t=0$

$$\begin{align*}\gamma'(0)\gamma^{-1}(0)+\gamma(0)(\gamma^{-1})'(0)&=0\\
A+(\gamma^{-1})'(0)&=0\end{align*}$$

Which implies that $(\gamma^{-1})'(0)=-A\in T_eG$. Now let $B\in T_eG$, to find $[A,B]$ we will use the adjoint representation of $\gamma$ acting on $B$

$$\text{Ad}(\gamma(t))(B)=\gamma(t)B\gamma^{-1}(t)$$

Evaluating the derivative at $t=0$ which corresponds to the derivative at $e$, gives us the Lie Bracket $[A,B]$

$$\begin{align}\text{ad}(A)(B)=[A,B]&=\left(\text{Ad}(\gamma(t))(B)\right)'(0)\\
&=\gamma'(0)B\gamma^{-1}(0)+\gamma(0)B(\gamma^{-1})'(0)\\
&=AB-BA\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for this approach. I should have specified in my post that I am trying to do this using the "local expression for Lie bracket" using the coordinate vector fields.

Comment: In that case make two curves $\gamma(t)$ and $\eta(t)$ such that $\gamma'(0)=A$ and $\eta'(0)=B$. These curves define vector fields $\gamma'(t)= \gamma'(t)^{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}$ and similarly for $\eta$. Computing the Lie Bracket at the identity will give the commutator of $A$ and $B$

Comment: You can also do the same thing as in the answer but by writing everything explicitly in local coordinates keeping in mind that the given computation was coordinate independent. There are many different ways of doing this of course but the common theme is to start with curves at the identity.